# Convergence of Poisson random variables with divergent parameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, poisson-distribution

There is a sequence of independent random Poisson variables $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots$ with divergent parameter $Y_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\frac{1}{n})$. Does this sequence converge almost surely? In $L^2$ space? In probability?

I am really confused as I did some research on my own and almost every question I come up to has to do with the sum of a sequence; but I do not believe this has to do anything with the sum of $Y_n$ right? to prove it converges almost surely, I have to prove that $Y_n$ approaches the limit of $e^{-1}*\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1/i$? Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why is the parameter $\frac1n$ divergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Y_n\geqslant 0$ a.s. we have
$$
\|Y_n\|_2 = \mathbb E[Y_n^2] = \mathsf{Var}(Y_n) + \mathbb E[Y_n^2] = \frac1n + \frac1n^2\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow0,
$$
so that $Y_n\to 0$ in $L^2$. This implies that $Y_n\to 0$ in probability. Moreover,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(Y_n\geqslant 1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-e^{-\frac1n}\right) = +\infty,
$$
so from the second Borel-Cantelli lemma we conclude that
$$
\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{Y_n\geqslant 1\}\right) = 1,
$$
and hence $Y_n$ does not converge to zero almost surely.